# Initialise char* at runtime with user input

Tags: c

I know this is possible

```
char text[A_BIG_NUMBER];
printf("Enter your name");
scanf("%s",text);
```

but is there a way to do this? (without using a char array as backup)

```
char* text;
printf("Enter your name");
scanf("%s",text);
```

while first way is easy but if A_BIG_NUMBER is not big enough to hold the string entered by user then it will create problems for the rest of the code, on the other hand if we use a large number then it wastes memory!

Thanks

**Edit: Sorry for the wrong tag. I am asking about C only.**

Comment: If you can assume POSIX, I recommend `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you say C++, the answer is "yes, string":

```
std::string name;

std::cout << "Enter your name: ";

if (!std::getline(std::cin, name)) { /* unexpected end of input */ }

// now use "name"
```

As you discovered, you generally need dynamic allocation to store external data. (Your code is not very general: you can't have very large automatic arrays, and the fixed size adds arbitrary magic numbers and constraints.) C++ is the perfect language for *encapsulating* the details of dynamic allocation *and cleanup*, so that you can use simple, automatic variables to do all the work for you.

If you don't like iostreams, you can rig up your own overload `bool getline(std::FILE *, std::string &)` that loops over calls to `std::fgets`  and `+=` to extract a complete line.

Comment: sorry for the wrong tag. I wanted something in C only. Sorry again

Comment: @YogenderSingh: I see. Shame. That would have been good to know.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use dynamically allocated memory instead of the array, but the fundamental issue of the overrun remains there:

```
char *text = malloc(A_BIG_NUMBER*sizeof(char));
printf("Enter your name");
scanf("%s",text);
```

You need to tell `scanf` that the space is limited, like this:

```
char text[201];
printf("Enter your name");
scanf("%200s",text);
```

Note that `text[201]` has an extra character space for the terminator: `%200s` limits the input to 200 "real" characters, so you need to provide an extra `char` for the `'\0'`.

Comment: hmmm yeah dynamic allocation gets away with array but as you mentioned you will still need to guess that A_BIG_NUMBER

Comment: @YogenderSingh On the other hand, the value of big number can get a lot bigger than if you use the stack allocation.

Answer (score 1):

char* does not allocate memory for storing the user input string and that is the reason the second code does not work.

If you are worried about the memory usage / wastage, you can overcome these limitations using program specific stack/heap.

Comment: means as such there is no way to do it without having a pre-allocated buffer?

Comment: Nope, C requires to have have some memory location allocated to store the string input.

Answer (score 0):

Use a small(ish) buffer with [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) in a loop. Inside the loop realloc() the final destination.

```
/* UNTESTED */
char smallish[1000];
char *destin = NULL;
size_t destin_size = 1;
while (fgets(smallish, sizeof smallish, stdin)) {
    destin_size += strlen(smallish);
    char *tmp = realloc(destin, destin_size);
    if (!tmp) /* deal with error */;
    destin = tmp;
    strcat(destin, smallish);
    if (smallish[strlen(smallish) - 1] == '\n') break;
}
/* use destin */
free(destin);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getchar, here is a sample code:

```
  int size = 128;
  char *s = (char*)malloc (size);
  char c;
  int i;
  while ((c = getchar ()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
      s[i] = c;
      ++i;
      if (i == size)
        {
          size = size * 2;
          char *tmp = realloc (s, size);
          if (tmp != NULL)
            s = tmp;
          else ; // error, try with malloc and copy or exit or whatever you want
        }
    }
  s[i] = 0;
```

Comment: If `realloc` fails, `s = realloc (s, size);` loses the reference to the allocated memory. It's safer to have a temporary and check whether `realloc` returned `NULL`.

Comment: char *s = (char*)malloc (size); still allocates the memory beforehand and its just another way of saying char s[128]; !!

Comment: @Yogender Singh, perhaps I am misunderstanding you but malloc allocates memory on the heap, while s[128] is allocated on the stack. It's quite different, in later case you cannot call realloc (s,new_size) without corrupting the heap.